# setInterval not working with content auto update

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to use this https://codepen.io/zeinab92/pen/xwWGWM

But It's not updating 'Hours, Minutes and Status' automatically without page reload.

How can I make it working so, times will automatically update and state text will also update based on the time condition whether it's Open or Closed.

I like the script except the auto update problem, I tried by create a new function,

```
setInterval(function() {
  $("#timeDiv").html(data);
}, 1000);
```

by disabling default

```
setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

or **setTimeout** instead of **setInterval**

But no luck.

Comment: Bear in mind time zones, the opening hours are in one and the user may be in another.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging, I found the problem with the code.

You have declared **now** as **global variable** outside **checkTime** function and when page loads **now** variable stores value of new Date i.e the value of Date when page has been loaded. Hence the value of now is updated only once as global variable are executed only once.

**Solution:** Place the **now** variable **inside checkTime** so that each time it will have new value of Date whenever checkTime is called.

```
function checkTime(){
var now=new Date();

....
}
```

Hope this resolves the issue. ([JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k267e4sf/))

Comment: As @AlexK. comment above, is it possible to implement time zone (gmt) function with the code?

Comment: But you have not mentioned condition for hours between 0 and 12.Still its working.Wonder how?For me when hour is less than 12 its not showing time